# Importing XML data into Access

Tags: xml, ms-access

I play a game called Warhammer 40,000 and am trying to import data from an XML file to Access DB. When I use the "Import from XML" it creates several tables but has several errors and barely imports any data. Many of the tables and fields in the data are blank anyway and thus aren't needed.

Here is the link to the data: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BSData/wh40k/master/Imperium%20-%20Astra%20Militarum.cat

Can someone assist in getting me the data I need? Or point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: The Access and Excel XML import "wizards" aren't very reliable.  Is there specific data you're trying to import from that file?  Also, is it a one-time thing, or something you'd want to update regularly?

Comment: It doesn't help that the file has a `.CAT` extension, nor that parts of it point to broken links, like `xmlns="http://www.battlescribe.net/schema/catalogueSchema"` which should be a schema.    I have a couple functions that you could use to load the XML with Access VBA and then parse the data semi-manually.  Is that something you'd be comfortable doing?

Comment: @Ashleedawg, yeah, I'd be comfortable doing that. Thank you for your research on it! I actually learned a lot about xml yesterday that I didn't know before.Sorry for the late response, I got frustrated ands had to step away for a bit.